# Angular service, have multiple instances instead of singleton?

Tags: angular, service, singleton

I understand by default services in angular are singleton. I have an event page that has cards, when i click the like button, the event component calls a service (call it userService) which add the event to an array then console logs the array so i can verify. Everything works nice however when i leave the event page and go back (using router), the array is empty again. I read a little about service singleton in the documentation but i can't seem to grasp the solution or the problem for that matter.

```
//this is the user.service.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  userModel: UserModel;

  constructor() { 
    this.userModel= new UserModel();
  }
  //adding liked to an arary.
  likedEvents(event: EventModel){
    this.userModel.likedevent.push(event);
    console.log(this.userModel.likedevent);
  }
}
```

and this is where i call

```
//this is event.component.ts
constructor(private userService:UserService, ) { }
  like(){
    alert('hi');
    this.event.title ='event Title';
    this.event.location ='event location';
    this.event.etablissement = 'event etablissemetn'
    this.event.type = 'happy hour'
    console.log(this.event);

    //here i call the service
    this.userService.likedEvents(this.event);
    this.userService.saveLikedEvents();
  }
```

What i don't understand is why the service has multiple instances, second how can i reduce it to one instance, i have read the documentation but i don't quite understand since i am new to angular.

UPDATE: in the navbar i was using href, i switched to routerlink and the problem is solved. However when refreshing the page it is still the same problem.

Comment: Do you also include the service in the component `providers`? If so, remove that line from the component declaration.

Comment: Perhaps you have added the service to a module somewhere, if you want a singleton, just don't add it to any module.

Comment: i only have app.module.ts, as you saw above in the service.ts i made it @injectable { providedIn:root} then in the component event.component.ts i imported the service.

Comment: Try to put a `console.log('...')` in the `constructor` of `UserService` to make sure the service is instantiated twice or if the problem lies somewhere else. If it logs only once, what is the class `UserModel` like?

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto i fixed the issue was href, i switch to routerlink,it works fine, but still the same problem on refresh i don't understand why

Comment: @ilyeshamrouni If you mean the refresh of the browser, the javascript is processed again and the service class is instantiated again, so that's to be expected. If you mean some custom refresh you implemented (that doesn't refresh the browser), then you should post the code (you could put a `console.log('...')` inside the `constructor` of the service and another inside the `constructor` of your model class to see what happens.

Comment: @LucasBasquerotto i mean the refresh of the browser, if that's expected, so i need to use localstorage so i make sure the service did not lose its  data if the user for whatever reason refreshes the page? Isn't there a better way ?

Comment: @ilyeshamrouni That depends on your use case. Let's say you have a url `/user/1` that shows the data of the user with id 1. When you refresh the browser, the only information you will have is the user id (1) and not the other data you had loaded before, so you could make a new request to the database and retrieve the data (after all, you have the id). If this data can be cached, you might very well cache it for performance. In your use case I don't know exactly what you do with that data. If it's only local, then localstorage seems like a good option to me (just save it with some unique key).

Comment: @ilyeshamrouni Think this way: when you refresh the browser, the only local data you will have is the url itself (aside from some static files like js, css, etc...), unless you have the data persisted it somehow, like using cookies and the localstorage. If the data you need is not (all of it) in the url, then you have to retrieve it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to store the state of the array, so why don´t you just use a "store"? I believe that NGRX suits your need!

The service is working fine. When route away from your component all the variables are no longer available, what the store does is make a copy somewhere else so that when you reload your page you can get the previous state.

Comment: Right! I worked a tiny bit with store in VueJs, i checked NGRX a little bit right now, and if i understand correctly, i have my models and services, and when i introduce the store, in the component i would dispatch an action which would call an effect that calls a service, which alters the state, and the state could be a model, So this solves my problem, but i already made some work and i think it would be tiring to integrate ngrx now plus the project isnt that big, so i prefer not implementing it, so is there no way i can make the variables always available when i route away?

Comment: There are more, and frankly easier options other than NGRX.

Comment: @ilyeshamrouni you can create a property bag to store the  state of the variables. It is easier than ngrx. If no one solves the issue I’ll share an example on stackblitz within 3/4 hours.

Comment: I'll look more into it, but any more help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can also recommend NGRX for its awesome instrumentation. You can use Redux DevTools to track your state, statechange, dispatched actions, timetravel in it or to freeze your state. If you choose to only use services, your only option to debug is `console.log`-ing out everything or using breakpoints. Even in a small scale application I'd recommend you to use ngrx. If your application is a CLI app, then you can use it to automatically generate most of the boilerplate code you need to write

Comment: @ZoltánSzepesi i might have to use NGRX, but  i don't understand why services don't work, isn't this the whole point of service singleton, so i can share data between components?

Comment: Probably if you provide your service in the root module your service's state would not get destroyed, but you usually write services to store static methods only. (Like api calls)

Comment: It's just a practice to use stores. It really depends on your needs. If you'd like to just display static content and nothing else then you should just use stateful services. But if you'd like to implement asynchronously loading stuff and errorhandling or dealing with offline mode then it's easier to use this pattern

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with the navbar i was using href.I fixed the problem by switching to routerlink